# rostopic publish message to remote machine?

Tags: ros, remote-roscore, publisher, rostopic, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I'm trying to connect to ROS running on a remote machine. I can remotely echo the topics from the machine however I cannot publish anything.

> rostopic echo /odom

works like a charm, printing all the odom messages published by the remote ROS on my local laptop.

> rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -- ""

however does not. I have traced the communication using Wireshark and all I can see are some `registerService`, `registerPublisher` and `getParam` commands. My message however doesn't arrive. I've also tried to simply publish a `std_msgs/String` to a topic called /blubb. But even that does not work. I cannot see the message itself on the network (however I can see the mentioned remote procedure calls) and thus it doesn't arrive at the remote machine.

`ROS_IP` is set to the remote machine's IP on both machines.
`ROS_MASTER_URI` is set to http://:11311 on both machines.

`netcat` works, `rostopic echo` does, `rqt_plot` does, even `rviz` does using the remote connection. I just can't send messages to the remote machine.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118576/rostopic-publish-message-to-remote-machine?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2014-01-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you've got the meaning of ROS_IP wrong. ROS_IP is to be set to each machine's ip, where a node is running. It is not something like ROS_MASTER_URI!

So, if you have machine a at 10.1.1.1 and machine b at 10.1.1.2, each node running on a must have ROS_IP 10.1.1.1 and each node on machine b ROS_IP 10.1.1.2. The reason is that machines need to be able to connect forth and back. That is why some connections work (in one direction), while others don't.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-01-16**:
See  http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup for an overview of networking setup.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-01-18**:
I see, I see. Thanks a lot! That has solved this problem.